# Words based on context for "logout" on websites?

Tags: translation

Two part question, would it be more common in German websites to have logout or signout(equivalents)? and what would be best to have as a general word in web applications?

I have found the following words for "Logout"

- abmelden
- ausmelden
- Fehlermeldung
- ausloggen

In Google translate, `ausloggen` is the word that came up, but I was not able to find any actual examples except for a forum where a contributor wrote

```
Ausloggen bei yahoo
```

And I found several other articles where people asked how to logout, they all seem to use that world `ausloggen`.

When I switched my google setting to German, the word that I saw was `abmelden` which (i think) translates to "Sign out".

Comment: *Fehlermeldung* means *error message*, is a substantive  and has nothing in common with the other choices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In German *Abmelden* and *Ausloggen* can be used as synonyms (in the context of websites). And while *Abmelden* might be a bit more common, both terms will be self-explanatory to a german user.

For example Amazon and Google (as you already saw) use *Abmelden* while PayPal uses *Ausloggen* in the german version of their websites.

A literal translation of signout in German, following the explanation in an [answer from ELL SE](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1362/difference-between-logoff-logout-signoff-and-signout) would be *(sich) austragen*, however this is not used at all on websites.

And just a hint regarding the translations of Logout you mentioned: *Fehlermeldung* means *error message*, which clearly doesn't fit and *ausmelden* is not even a (german) word.